# Decimal expansion of the number $f_3(3)$ with PARI/GP?

Tags: number-theory, math-software, big-numbers

I tried to calculate the number $f_3(3)$ with PARI/GP. It seems the number is too large to be calculated exactly. I would like to analyze the full decimal expansion.

> Is there any trick to get all the digits ?

The number $f_3(3)$ is equal to $2^{402653211}\cdot 3$ having $121210695$ digits. I neither could display this number nor could I create the vector of its digits via "digits(n)". What can I do ?

UPDATE : I managed to store two numbers that could , concatenated , give the desired number. Of course, I cannot submit those numbers, but I will give the last digits of the first number and the first digits of the second number. I verfiied the first digits of the first number and the last digits of the second number. Apaarently, they are correct.

The last digits of the first number are

$$67339748680554085197019302058095933154479550517126426860727584719$$

The first number should be the integer part of the desired number divided by $10^{65\ 000\ 000}$

The first digits of the second number are $$811321643909024984450993111987746601114078967737295129933845859521$$

The second number should be the rest of the decimal expansion of the desired number. Can anyone approve those digits ?

Comment: I would write my own `C++` program to multiply and square numbers in base $10$.

Comment: Can Pari store the number in a file in a usable form ?

Comment: @Gribouillis Unfortunately no, I get the message "overflow in lg()"

Comment: What is strange : Although the number is calculated very quickly (so I have doubt that it is actually calculated exactly), I can recover the factorization or modulo-calculations with the number easily. Now I try to create the digit-vector the hard way (be removing digit by digit)

Comment: The binary representation of the number is $11$ followed by $402653211$ zeroes. This may be the reason why it is calculated very quickly.

Comment: I could store the last $65$ million digits of the number. To get the first $60$ million digits however did not work.

Comment: Will PARI/GP accept to divide the number by $10^{65000000}$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis Seems to work, but I am not able to read the number with the PARI-program. I will show the first and last digits of both numbers I have stored. Maybe someone can verify whether those numbers concatenated give the desired decimal expansion.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not about PARI/GP directly. Any computational system with **sufficient** time and storage could do the job. Essentially, you need to compute $a^bc$ for some positive integers $a,b,c$ using squaring and multiplication. First you need to decide how many decimal digits you can store in RAM comfortably. Let us use a million digits for concreteness. You just store the intermediate and final numbers in a collection of disk files, each having at most a million digits. To multiply $A*B$ use the standand radix representation multiplication algorithm on numbers, but in this case our radix is $R:=10^{\textrm{million}},$ a million decimal digits. We read two of the files to get $A_i$ and $B_j$, multiply them together and split the product into  $A_i*B_j=C*R+D$ and add this to the accumulating partial product. PARI/GP and other similar programs do all this internally. Finally, the complete product will be stored on disk as a collection of files ready for further processing.

However, having written a general plan, I confess that PARI/GP is quite capable of computing the number in a few seconds. I used the statement $\;\texttt{n=3*2^402653211;}$ The size in bytes given by $\texttt{sizebyte(n)}$ is $50331660$. Actually getting the digits is another matter. The last $50$ digits using $\texttt{n%10^50}$ is $57619658951446422310193135419323844928197722374144$ which agrees with

```
? lift(3*Mod(2,10^50)^402653211)
57619658951446422310193135419323844928197722374144
```

You would get better answers by asking on the [pari-users mailing list](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/lists-index.html).

Edit: Note that for intermediate writing/reading disk it is important to use binary formats to avoid tremendous slowdown in converting to/from decimal. In PARI/GP that means using $\texttt{writebin()}$ instead of $\texttt{write()}.$

Comment: Well, the problem is that PARI/GP apparently cannot well handle such huge numbers. It is strange that the number can (if this is actually the case) be calculated fast EXACTLY but that the digits are not easy to be determined. Maybe, there are better programs, but my question is what I can do with PARI/GP. To determine the first or last few digits is easy, to do that we do not even need much memory. Now I try to seperate the digits in blocks of length $10^5$. This takes very long, but perhaps I can analyze the digits this way. Let's see ...

Comment: @Peter The primary limitation is stack space. You need to use $\textrm{allocatemem()}$ to ensure enough stack space. Also you **have** to tell us exact error messages. Just writing "I am not able to read the number with the PARI-program" does not help to understand the reason.

Comment: My maximum is $1024$ M-byte. This was enough to store the above numbers, but I could not import them with the read-command. But there is a possibility that I just had not enough patience. I had no error message, but it seems to take an eternity (if it even works)

Comment: @Peter A suggestion. When writing to disk it is better to use $\texttt{writebin()}$ to avoid the slowness when reading it back. It will help tremendously.

Comment: Thank you for that tip!

Comment: But strangely, a single number with $3$ million digits can easily be recovered, also a number with $3\cdot 10^5$ and a number with $3\cdot 10^6$. But when I wrote the $41$ numbers with writebin() , I could not recover even the first number. Apparently, PARI/GP couldn't read the file. Can you suggest another program for such tasks, but like PARI/GP, it should be free and exectuable with windows. I have GAP, can I do it with this program ?

Comment: Try $\texttt{x=123; writebin("abc",x); y=read("abc"); print(y);}$