# Can I avoid the overflow which I get with the digits of $f_3(3)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion, big-numbers

I would like to ananlyze the digits of the number $$f_3(3)$$ which is defined as follows :

Start with $\ n=3\ $ and apply the opration $\ n\cdot 2^n\ $ three times. The first iteration gives $\ 24\ $, the second $\ 2^{27}\cdot 3\ $ and the third $$2^{402653211}\cdot 3$$

This number has $$121\ 210\ 695$$ digits.

Now, the problem arises. If I try to calculate the digit-vector of this number with pari/gp with "$v=digits(n)$", the stack overflows even if I choose my personal maximum stack size (which is $4$ Gigabytes) .

> Is there a possibility to access the digits avoiding this overflow-issue ?

Comment: Are you familiar with writing codes in another languages $($ i.e C++ , python etc .. $) \, ?$

Comment: No, would python solve this problem ?

Comment: See also this old post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575516/decimal-expansion-of-the-number-f-33-with-pari-gp?rq=1

Comment: That number written in binary is very simple. To obtain the digits in decimal notation for a number $M$ you only need compute remainder after division by $10$ and quotient. The remainder is the last digit and the quotient is the next number on which you need to apply the same two steps. Store in a vector the binary representation $110000...0$, with $402653211$ zeros. Then you need to implement  division and remainder by $10$ and loop

Comment: Better ask on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for more appropriate answers.

Comment: @cardinalRed This seems to take an eternity. Moreover, I get the digits in reversed order this way.

Comment: It shouldn't take an eternity. Who knows what exactly you did. Yes, the digits get computed starting from the less significative. Not a problem, store them and print them in order.

Comment: @cardinalRed $(1)$ I cannot store them, otherwise the simple digit-command would work as well. $(2)$ The operation (n-d)/10 , where d is the current digit, seems to take very long , if n is huge. This algorithm is not difficult to implement, so I wonder why you assume I could not implement it correctly. Or what did you mean else with "who knows ..." ?

Comment: Still Mathematica handles this easily, I've printed its digits to a file, it took about half a minute perhaps.

Comment: @Sil Nice, but I do not have Mathematica ...

Comment: Problem is that each of the tools have their own way to convert the efficient binary representation to the decadic representation when printing to output, so it causes overflows, stucks, etc, somehow Mathematica has this optimized, it is hard to tell where is the exact problem without seeing their implementation. By the way the digits file has pretty poor compression ratio about 2:1, so at least according to deflate it looks quite "random".

Comment: Nevertheless I suggest you to get Mathematica, since you do quite a lot of intensive computations and Mathematica is just superior to pari/gp or even Maple when it comes to performance (mostly).

Comment: @Sil OK, but why is 2:1 a poor compression ratio ? I would conisder this highly compressible and far away from random.

Comment: Just based on the experience on previous projects, we considered anything below 5:1 to be undesirable (under small storage constraints) and we usually had like 10:1 or sometimes even 20:1 ratios, but yea it was totally diferent data, so who knows.

Comment: Anyway if you want the digits I can upload them somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102381/discussion-between-peter-and-sil).

Comment: handle in log form.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I want to calculate the exact value, not just an approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to insist on PARI/GP, then just process the digits in chunks. Of course it means that you need to update your algorithm (whatever it will be doing) to be able to work in a sort of streaming fashion - process available chunk of digits (e.g. update statistics), move on to the next chunk, etc... Using following approach, I was able to read the digits with using at about 300MB at the peak:

```
default(parisize, 600000000) // setting approx 572.205 Mbytes, can be probably lowered
x = 3 * (1 << 402653211);
W = 10000000000;

t = x % W; // store least significant 10 digits to a temporary variable
x = truncate(x/W); // move on to next 10 digits

// now process 10 digits however you want stored in t (at this point t=7722374144)
v = digits(t);

t = x % W; // store least significant 10 digits to a temporary variable
x = truncate(x/W); // move on to next 10 digits

// process further digits (at this point t=2384492819)

...
```

All these commands were done pretty much instantly, so if you put it into the loop it should be still reasonably fast. Now you can experiment with required memory size and used window size.

Also, I would compare the performance of this approach with just reading digit by digit (basically window size of $10$), it is possible it will be fast enough by itself.